# Using Custom Helper in a Custom Helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a custom helper (`MessageHelper`) in which I need access to another custom helper (`IncentiveHelper`). I've followed the format described in the docs, but I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined property: MessageHelper::$Incentive [APP/views/helpers/message.php, line 21]
```

Here's the relevant chunk of code. To my eye, it looks virtually identical to that in the [1.3 docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1098/Including-other-Helpers):

```
class MessageHelper extends AppHelper {
  public $helpers = array( 'Incentive' );

  public function rebates( $rebates ) {
    debug( $this->Incentive ); exit;
  }
}
```

The files are named and stored according to convention as `app/views/helpers/message.php` and `app/views/helpers/incentive.php`. On a whim, I did try including a core helper (`HtmlHelper`) instead, but that failed the same way.

What am I missing here? Is there something obvious that I'm just not seeing? Seems like there must be, but my eyes are starting to cross. Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: the key question is: how are you importing/including your message helper? in the controller via `public $helpers = array('Message')`?

Comment: Hmmm. That's a good point. In this case, I think I'm using it in a controller (don't judge) and using `App::import()`. I think you're on to something.

Comment: see, thats your problem. dont do that :). failure by design - make it a lib or a component and use it the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in cakephp, but I think you may be looking for something like http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php